# Is there a hadith about Friday prayer (Jumu'ah) being centralized and grouped in one place?

Tags: hadith, prayer-timings, jumuah

I'm not sure whether it's culture or if it has roots in hadith, but I feel the Jumu'ah (Friday prayer) should be a centralized event, by which I mean that if in one region there are several mosques, only one of them should host the Jumu'ah salah. Can someone bring up relevant texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My answer is based on my understanding that this question actually touches the subject of usool-e-deen i.e. sources of deen.*

1. It is not culture but Sunnah. Sunnah itself is an independent source of Deen just like Quran.
2. Note: By Sunnah I do not mean Hadith. Sunnah, like Quran, has reached us through `consensus` and `perpetual practice` of all the Muslim generations since the Prophet i.e. Muslims offer Friday prayer in congregation because every `generation` has seen the earlier `generation` offering it like this and this chain goes back to the prophet.
3. So, asking for a Hadith is just like asking for historical record of a Sunnah which you see live.
4. Your feeling about it being a centralized event is not wrong. It is corroborated by the fact that according to Sunnah it has to be conducted by [Muslim rulers](http://www.monthly-renaissance.com/issue/query.aspx?id=862). The rightly guided and umayyad caliphs always followed this.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following aya is enough to answer for your question ...

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا إذا نودي للصلاة من يوم الجمعة فاسعوا إذا ذكر الله
>   وذروا البيع، ذلكم خير لكم ان كنتم تعلمون سورة الجمعة:9
>
> O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on
>   the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the remembrance of Allah
>   and leave trade. That is better for you, if you only knew.
>   [Al-Jumu'a:9]

Where according to the aya plural form "فاسعوا" in the sense of congregations

so in this aya indicates that it should be presence Friday and listen to the khutbah

Comment: -1 this doesn't address the question at all: is there anything in the texts to encourage the "grouping" of congregations?

Comment: Yes According to the aya plural form "فاسعوا" in the sense of congregations